# How to handle permissions for route from database?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

In Vue, when I want to restrict some pages for some users, in router I define a permission in meta, like this:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: 'transport',
        name: 'transport',
        component: Transport,
        meta: { permission: "edit_transport" }
    },
]
```

When user logins I have its JWT where I can find what permission he/she has and in `route.beforeEach`, I check if user has this permission, he/she can visit a page.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('user_token');

    if(to.meta.permission == 'edit_transport') {
       //if user's token has edit_tranport permission let him visit the page
    }
})
```

But, now I have this permissions In database, there is a table where admin defines permission for page:

```
id     permision         page
_____________________________________
1      edit_transport    transport
2      write_post        create_post
```

This means, for example user needs `edit_transport` permission to visit transport page.

My solution is: first I have to take all this permissions from database and save them in `vuex` store, and then access this store data in `route.beforeEach` and check what permission page needs and then check if user has this permission

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('user_token');
    let pagepermission = store.permissions[to.name]
    if (token.has(pagepermission)) {
        // let user visit the page
    } else {
        // redirect
    }
})
```

So, is it a good way or is there any other way better then this?

Comment: It's what I would do, as long as there is an additional server-side permission check on those pages as well, which applies to your previous solution also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good check to do on the client side, if you are also protecting routes / endpoints on the back end I think that would be the most well rounded solution.

I'm not sure what you're using on the backend but if its Node, you could use something like [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) to manage roles - as a middleware to routes and endpoints.